# Rails: Rollback Mistake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rollback, dbmigrate

I have created a table called "property" and I did not migrate it yet.  I then wanted to delete the table, so when I did `rake db:rollback` as below.  My previously created table, which I did not want to delete at all, is now reverted.  How should I revive my model "comment" and instead delete the last model "property" only.

Some comments say do "redo" or "run migrate" but if I do a `rake db:migrate`, I feel like it will delete the comment model permanently.  Am I wrong?  What is right solution to bring back my comment model?

```
:~/workspace (revoke) $ rails g model property title address note price$ priceW 
Running via Spring preloader in process 3066
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20160517222114_create_properties.rb
      create    app/models/property.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/property_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/properties.yml
:~/workspace (revoke) $ bundle exec rake db:rollback
== 20160506122941 CreateComments: reverting ===================================
-- drop_table(:comments)
   -> 0.0011s
== 20160506122941 CreateComments: reverted (0.0096s) ==========================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've done the `rake db:rollback`, you've made a change to the database.   In this case, it dropped your `comments` table, as you can see in the output: `drop_table(:comments)`.  The data is gone, already.  We've all been there at least once.

Running `rake db:migrate` will restore the `comments` table structure, but not the data in it.  In this situation, if you want to get to the point that your new table `property` isn't migrated, you can run `rake db:migrate` to run all new migrations, and then `rake db:rollback` once to rollback the migration for `property`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there anyway to restor the data in the comments table?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not a standard way.  If you have your log files, you can probably resurrect the contents of `comments` from there, but it will require some searching.  You'll want to locate the log entries that are POST to your `/comments` route (or `/parent/comments` if it's nested) and look for the `params` hash for the action.

Comment: Sounds really difficult.. but thanks so much for the info~!

Comment: It just depends on how badly you want that data back.  Most times, especially in the development environment, it's not worth the effort.  However, if you were in a production environment, you might have to go through all of that effort to restore crucial data.